# Not allowing to Install any packages

Tags: software-installation, mysql-workbench

While Trying to install through command line, I am facing this error

```
E: The package mysql-workbench-community needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a backup of /var/lib/dpkg/status:

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.old
```

Noe open  the file /var/lib/dpkg/status:

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Search through the file for the entry of mysql-workbench-community usnig <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, delete that entry then save and close the file.

Now run :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: you are welcome.  If you like my answer, just click the little grey ☑ under the "0" now turning it into  green.